# Error when restarting csf on DirectAdmin server running centos

Tags: centos, csf

I just installed csf on a DirectAdmin server running CentOS. When i restart csf it however says:

```
Restarting bandmin acctboth chains for cPanel
    open3: exec of /usr/local/bandmin/bandminstart failed at /usr/sbin/csf line 3168
    iptables v1.3.5: Couldn't load target `acctboth':/lib64/iptables/libipt_acctboth.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

    Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
    iptables v1.3.5: Couldn't load target `acctboth':/lib64/iptables/libipt_acctboth.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

    Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
    iptables v1.3.5: Couldn't load target `acctboth':/lib64/iptables/libipt_acctboth.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

    Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
    iptables v1.3.5: Couldn't load target `acctboth':/lib64/iptables/libipt_acctboth.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

    Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
    LOCALOUTPUT  all opt -- in * out !lo  0.0.0.0/0  -> 0.0.0.0/0
    LOCALINPUT  all opt -- in !lo out *  0.0.0.0/0  -> 0.0.0.0/0
```

Any idea why it's doing this? cPanel isn't even installed :s I tried restarting iptables but that didn't solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have a mismatch of versions (most likely).

You can just opt to ignore them (warnings).

OR

You can turn off bandmin with csf by looking for setting LF_*_BANDMIN, setting to false (* should be replaced by something else) and restart csf/lfd.

OR

You can find where you have bandmin (check /scripts/bandminup) and update or install

OR

You can try to update both direct-admin, centos (various dependencies) and csf and cross your fingers for luck.

Comment: However, bandmin comes from cPanel. http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/11_30/WHMDocs/BandmindPass Bandmin is therefore not installed..

Answer (score 0):

It appeared that i did something stupid. When I loaded the default csf.conf it appeared the default one was for cPanel. When rechecking the distribution file it appeared that there was also one called 'csf.directadmin.conf. When you rename that one to csf.conf and upload it to the server, it will solve the problem.

Comment: At least I was right about the version mismatch part. ^^;

Comment: hahaha yeah true indeed